# User-Defined settings for WatchKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist, watchkit, xcode-6.2

I am using User-Defined settings (for example `CustomAppBundleId`) to change bundle identifier for different configurations. In the app’s plist file I set `CFBundleIdentifier` to `${CustomAppBundleId}`. For Release configuration I use bundle:

```
com.yourcompany.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}
```

and for AdHoc I use:

```
com.yourcompany.adhoc.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}
```

Now I added WatchKit Extension and WatchKit App. For WatchKit Extension bundle identifier I can use the same approach. I also have to change `WKAppBundleIdentifier` to match the bundle identifier in the WatchKit App. Again, I could use  User-Defined settings. Now the last bit is WatchKit App. Unfortunately WatchKit App doesn’t have an option to add User-Defined settings but I need to set the right values for `CFBundleIdentifier` and `WKCompanionAppBundleIdentifier` (that is equal to `CustomAppBundleId` in the app). Is there any way I can do it? Or should I use different approach?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38328837/change-user-defined-variable-from-fastlane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your "User-Defined" variables in project's Build Settings rather than in target's. That way you will have the same user defined variables automatically available (inherited) in WatchKit Extension and App target.

---

Btw make sure you have the latest Xcode 6.3 from the App Store. This version (and most recent Xcode 6.3 beta 4) already allow you to define custom "User-Defined" in Build Settings).

Previous versions were simply missing "Build Settings" tab in WatchKit App target, but if you were brave enough, you could have modify those manually in plain text editor :-)

Answer (score 0):

Update to Xcode 6.3.

In 6.3 you will have additional tabs for target configuration that should provide what you need.

But I'm almost sure you will face issues with the WatchKit App Storyboard.
In the `Scenes > Identity Inspector > Custom Class` you have to set the correct module - that is not possible if you have more than 1 (if you do not have more than one I would be more than interested in your setup)

I solved that issue with a pre-action script that updates the storyboard XML accordingly